# Perl Regex Capture Into Array

Tags: regex, perl

Why does this code:

```
my $text = "!a!b!c!";
my @captures = ($text =~ /!(.)!/g);
print "$_\n" foreach @captures;
```

output only

```
a
c
```

?

Expected output:

```
a
b
c
```

How can I capture all of them?

Comment: Use a lookahead in order not to consume the second `!`: `($text =~ /!(.)(?=!)/g);`. However, your code outputs `a` and `c`, not only `a`.

Comment: Why not just do `my @matches = split "!", "!a!b!c!";`

Comment: @hwnd this was just an abstract problem in trying to better understand captures, but your approach is useful as well thanks

Comment: @stribizhev thank you!

Comment: I would expect it to output "a\nc\n".  And testing here, that's what I get.  Is that really the code you're running, and are you really not getting the "c"?  If so: What version of perl are you using, and how are you running this code?

Comment: @TheSidhekin you're right, it does output "a\nc\n". I've edited the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a look-ahead in order not to consume the second `!` and keep it for the next regex engine iteration:

```
/!(.)(?=!)/g
```

First, `!` is matched, then any symbol but a newline that is right before a `!` that is not consumed, the regex engine index stays right before it. So, the next match can start with this `!`.

Updated code:

```
my $text = "!a!b!c!";
my @captures = ($text =~ /!(.)(?=!)/g);
print "$_\n" foreach @captures;
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Splitting with `!` can turn out a more effecient alternative in the currently posted scenario:

```
my $text = "!a!b!c!";
my @matches = grep /\S/, split "!", $text;
print "$_\n" foreach @matches;
```

Note that `grep /\S/` will remove empty or whitespace-only elements from the array obtained with `split`.